# what is the lemma that each iteration will pick the vertex with minimum distance value in Dijkstra Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Here is the pseudocode from Wikipedia:

```
 1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3      create vertex set Q
 4
 5      for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
 6          dist[v] ← INFINITY                  // Unknown distance from source to v
 7          prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                 // Previous node in optimal path from source
 8          add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
 9
10      dist[source] ← 0                        // Distance from source to source
11      
12      while Q is not empty:
13          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Node with the least distance will be selected first
14          remove u from Q 
15          
16          for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
17              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
18              if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
19                  dist[v] ← alt 
20                  prev[v] ← u 
21
22      return dist[], prev[]
```

This is a greedy process. What confusing me is line 13: why is the node with the least distance necessarily selected first?  What is the theory or lemma behind it?

**Modified:**

Before u is extract from Q, dist[u] is INFINITY, or corresponding to u's "Estimated Distance" in the paper mentioned by Yonggoo Noh

Comment: Do you mean "why doesn't it work to pick a node other than the least distance node" or do you mean "why does it work to pick the least distance node" (or do you mean *how* is it selected)?

Comment: `each iteration will pick the vertex with minimum distance value` The next vertex is picked by taking the first element in a list sorted by ascending distance. This guarantees the node is minimal in that list.

Comment: @Dukeling  "why does it work to pick the least distance node in each iteration"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find easily proofs of Dijkstra's algorithm.

The one of them is: http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/w10/dijkstra.pdf

In that link,

> **Lemma 2** Let *v_m* be an outside vertex in *V−S* such that *d_m* is minimum.
>   Then *d_m* ≤ *d_j* , for all *j ∈ V−S*. That is, the estimated distance to *v_m* is a lower bound on the length of the shortest path from *s* to any vertex in *V−S*.

For detailed proofs of Dijkstra, please see that link.

Comment: Just to confirm, in the paper it defines estimate distance "dest j = min di + w(ei,j)" , it means destj = min(di + w(ei,j)), right?

Answer (score 1):

This is to ensure that the *first* solution found is the *shortest*.  At each choice point, you work on the shortest known (partial) path.  When you finally hit a terminal (success) node, the completed path *must* be the shortest, because all uncompleted paths are already longer.